# Can a Django app be run directly from python?

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I have created an app with Django, on my Raspberry Pi, as part of my smart home project. Now that I am coming to the end of the project, I would like to make it so that I can run one script and have all of the features of the smart home working. (This would be especially useful as then I can just make it run on boot without having to connect a screen or ssh).

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can make a python script that will run the whole Django app so that I don't have to go into terminal and set it up. Is this possible? and if not what is the best way to go about my issue?

Comment: Normally, I would set up Apache to do this, although I'm not sure if you are capable of installing it on Raspberry Pi. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for details. Essentially, you need a secure mechanism by which to listen to a port on your machine and then forward the traffic to your python app. [nginx](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that you set the `autologin` in `raspi-config` then create a shell script `run.sh`

like this

`python /path/to/project.manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

or you can use `gunicorn` proxy

You can also start other servers in this file

then put `sh run.sh` in you `.bashrc`.

**Better way**

You can install tmux by `apt-get install tmux`
You can make detached session using [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux)  in `run.sh` using a unique name and `tmux` so that each time you open the prompt it wont create duplicate sessions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i decided to use the run.sh method and it is working perfectly!